# Escaping special characters in a variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, escaping

I have a variable in PowerShell that contains special characters like "<",">" and double quotes. Currently I am using something like `-replace ">" , "^>"` ,
`-replace "<" , "^<"`, `-replace '"' , "'"`. Is there a way to escape all special characters in this variable?

Comment: Rule of escapement fully depend on who will use escaped string. For example for regular expressions it would be `[Regex]::Escape`, but for wildcard patterns you should use `[WildcardPattern]::Escape`. Also there are special methods for XML, URL and so on. Each use case have its own set of special characters and escapement rules.

Comment: Are you saying the variable's _name_ contains special characters, or are you saying the variable's _value_ contains special characters?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart It looks like contents.  Also, why are you (OP) using `^` to escape?  Are you dynamically creating a batch file?

Comment: I had a text file that contained some sql queries delimited by semicolons, and I was using for loop to loop through those statements for execution: e.g. `foreach ($q in (gc text.txt) -join "" -split ";" -replace ">","^>" -replace ... {...code...}`. My sql statements contain double quotes and angle brackets, which I found they kind of affected the command execution. (e.g. the double quotes in the queries get removed in the submitted version, causing errors)

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the variable in *curly* brackets, i.e.,

```
${<My-Variable>with<Special-Characters>} ="<test>"
${<My-Variable>with<Special-Characters>}
```

Returns

```
<test>
```

The below is taken from another post on Stack Overflow, but I can’t find the link.

If it is the variable that contains *special characters*, this should work. Within the `@" "@`  delimiters, variables and sub-expressions will get expanded, but quotes and other special characters are treated as literals.

```
$SpecialCharacters = @'
& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -mx5 -tzip -r "$DestFileZip" "$DestFile"
'@

$SpecialCharacters
```

Comment: The **variable contents** contain special characters.  Not the variable name itself.

Comment: what if I need **not** to escape $DestFileZip? E.g `$DestFileZip = "my-value"` and the content print `my-value`